# Map Caps Lock to Backspace and Caps lock to Some other shortcut using Autohotkey

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

How can I turn <kbd>caps lock</kbd> to <kbd>backspace</kbd> using autohotkey? I also want to add some kind of shortcut to toggle <kbd>caps lock</kbd> by mapping shortcut like <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>. I am using windows 32 bit Standard account, where I do not have administrative privellages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can't make shortcuts out of Caps Lock and Backspace in Windows

Comment: I used colemak portable layout and it has set caps lock set to backspace and to toggle caps lock it has shortcut Shift+Caps Lock. I want to get same functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+CapsLock::CapsLock ; toggles CapsLock on and off when you hold down Shift and press CapsLock (+ is the symbol for Shift)

Capslock::Backspace ; makes CapsLock become Backspace
```

If both [remapping](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#toc)s allow additional modifier keys to be held down (it doesn't apply in this case because Backspace isn't a modifier), the more specific `+CapsLock::CapsLock` remapping must be placed first for it to work.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#other-useful-remappings